# How to do multiline pattern matching in text file

Tags: regex, awk, vim

I am getting the below file from test results and this file contains 100000 or more entries of test cases.

File Content:

```
Iteration is 1
Testcase is passed
Iteration is 2
Testcase is passed
Iteration is 3
Testcase is passed
Iteration is 4
Testcase is failed
Iteration is 5
Testcase is failed
Iteration is 6
Iteration is 7
Testcase is failed
Iteration is 8
Iteration is 9
Iteration is 10
Testcase is failed
Iteration is 11
Testcase is passed
```

For some test case iteration like `6`, `8`, `9` verdict is missing.There is no pass or fail for those iterations.

I just want to find for which iteration test case verdict is missing.

I opened file in gvim and tried to find and delete pattern like  `Iteration is .*\n.*passed` and `Iteration is .*\n.*failed` but it didn't work .

Can anyone suggest how to find  iterations for which there is no verdict like

```
Iteration is 6
Iteration is 8
Iteration is 9
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a "find" in any decent editor using the following regex:

```regex
Iteration is \d+\nTestcase is \w+\n
```

and replace the matches with an empty string.

For example in vim, assuming the cursor is at the beginning of the file

```
:1,$s/Iteration is \d\+\nTestcase is \w\+\n//
```

does the trick.

Once done, the file will contain the lines with no tallying fail/pass result.

You could also use the same tactic to write a perl script - I leave that to you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple Vim solution:

```
:g/passed\|failed/norm k2dd
```

Explanation:

- `:g/<pattern>/<command>` executes `<command>` on every line matching `<pattern>`.
- `passed\|failed` is our pattern. It matches both lines with `passed` and lines with `failed`. Think of `\|` as "or": "match with `passed` or `failed`".
- `norm k2dd` is our command. `:help :norm` is used to execute normal mode commands outside of normal mode. Here we are…

  - moving the cursor to the line above the matched line with `k`,
  - deleting two lines with `2dd`, effectively removing from the file all iterations with a passed or failed test case.

We are left with the following lines in the buffer:

```
Iteration is 6
Iteration is 8
Iteration is 9
```

and we can revert that change with `u` once we have the information we need.

Comment: I did the approx same thing by recording Macros --> search passed keyword, go one line above, and delete 2 lines. repeat this Macro n number of times. but above solution is very clean . Thanks for it.

Comment: Recording is a neat feature but I have found out that I prefer more explicit ways. Case in point: it is hard to know how many times to play back the recording you describe so you end up either guessing or using arbitrarily large numbers. This is too magical for me. With `:help :g` that kind of detail becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk '
    /^Iteration/ {
        if (prev) print prev
        prev = $0
    }
    /^Testcase/ {
        prev = ""
    }
    END {
        if (prev) print prev
    }
' file.txt
```

Result:

```
Iteration is 6
Iteration is 8
Iteration is 9
```

- A variable `prev` holds the previous `Iteration` record.
- When the record starts with `Iteration` and the variable `prev` is set,
  it means the last `Iteration` record do not have the corresponding pass/fail
  record.
- When the record starts with `Testcase`, the variable `prev` is cleared.
- The `END {}` block handles the last iteration.